# Wait for location pathname to change in useEffect and test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm looking for some help with testing component. In my case in the effect I'm doing this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (lodashHas(meetings[0], 'id')) {
      history.push(`${routes.zoomMeetings}/${meetings[0].id}`);
    }
  }, [meetings, key]);
```

I would like to wait until this effect applies and make testing. However, when I'm testing it with:

```
expect(window.location.pathname).toBe(`${routes.zoomMeetings}/${meetingsListInfo.meetings[0].id}`)
```

It still shows me `/` as a path instead of proper pathname. When I'm console logging I can see in the terminal the effect is working. It feels like the test is not waiting for this effect to evaluate before doing assertions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `useHistory` from `react-router-dom` like the following:

```
const history = useHistory();
```

In my tests I'm trying to mock `history.push()`. I've managed to solve it by doing this in my test:

```
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

let history;

const renderComponent = () => {
    history = createMemoryHistory();

    render(<Router history={history}><MyComponent /></Router>);
}

it('tests location changes', () => {
    renderComponent();

    const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(history, 'push');

    expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(`some-route`);
    expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

This way I can test assertions properly.